Segmented::segmented() Error in obj0$residuals : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
I'm trying to run a segmented linear regression on Net-Sqaured Displacement data of an animal to find a breakpoint in its behaviour. When I attempt to fit the segmented() function on my lm, I get the error: "Error in obj0$residuals : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors."
My interpretation is that the segmented() is unable to access the residuals of my lm() to find the breakpoint.
Reproducible example:
data <- data.frame(x = lubridate::ymd_hms(c("2022-05-23 21:00:43", "2022-05-23 23:00:37",
"2022-05-24 01:00:36", "2022-05-24 03:00:36",
"2022-05-24 05:00:09", "2022-05-24 07:00:37", 
"2022-05-24 09:00:44", "2022-05-24 11:00:37",
"2022-05-24 13:00:38", "2022-05-24 15:00:36",
"2022-05-24 17:00:36", "2022-05-24 19:00:38", 
"2022-05-24 21:00:38", "2022-05-24 23:00:36", "2022-05-25 01:00:38", 
"2022-05-25 03:00:38", "2022-05-25 05:00:38", "2022-05-25 07:00:24", 
"2022-05-25 09:00:37", "2022-05-25 11:00:12", "2022-05-25 13:00:37", 
"2022-05-25 15:00:38", "2022-05-25 17:00:36", "2022-05-25 19:00:35", 
"2022-05-25 21:00:37", "2022-05-25 23:00:38", "2022-05-26 01:00:37", 
"2022-05-26 03:00:38", "2022-05-26 05:00:36", "2022-05-26 07:00:38", 
"2022-05-26 09:00:37", "2022-05-26 11:00:42", "2022-05-26 13:00:37", 
"2022-05-26 15:00:38", "2022-05-26 17:00:38", "2022-05-26 19:00:37", 
"2022-05-26 21:00:36", "2022-05-26 23:00:36", "2022-05-27 01:00:38", 
"2022-05-27 03:00:36", "2022-05-27 05:00:36", "2022-05-27 07:00:12", 
"2022-05-27 09:00:37", "2022-05-27 11:00:36", "2022-05-27 13:00:37", 
"2022-05-27 15:00:38", "2022-05-27 17:00:38", "2022-05-27 19:00:35", 
"2022-05-27 21:00:38", "2022-05-27 23:00:36", "2022-05-28 01:00:38", 
"2022-05-28 03:00:36", "2022-05-28 05:00:37", "2022-05-28 07:00:13", 
"2022-05-28 09:00:37", "2022-05-28 11:00:44", "2022-05-28 13:00:37", 
"2022-05-28 15:00:14", "2022-05-28 17:00:37", "2022-05-28 19:00:36", 
"2022-05-28 21:00:38", "2022-05-28 23:00:36", "2022-05-29 01:00:42", 
"2022-05-29 03:00:38", "2022-05-29 05:00:38", "2022-05-29 07:00:36", 
"2022-05-29 09:00:38", "2022-05-29 11:00:14", "2022-05-29 13:00:37", 
"2022-05-29 15:00:36", "2022-05-29 17:00:38", "2022-05-29 19:00:36", 
"2022-05-29 21:00:38", "2022-05-29 23:00:38", "2022-05-30 01:00:36", 
"2022-05-30 03:00:37", "2022-05-30 05:00:38", "2022-05-30 07:00:37", 
"2022-05-30 09:00:38", "2022-05-30 11:00:36", "2022-05-30 13:00:14", 
"2022-05-30 15:00:37", "2022-05-30 17:00:36", "2022-05-30 19:00:36", 
"2022-05-30 21:00:36", "2022-05-30 23:00:15", "2022-05-31 01:00:37", 
"2022-05-31 03:00:32", "2022-05-31 05:00:35", "2022-05-31 07:00:14", 
"2022-05-31 09:00:37", "2022-05-31 11:00:10", "2022-05-31 13:00:37", 
"2022-05-31 15:00:15", "2022-05-31 17:00:37", "2022-05-31 19:00:36", 
"2022-05-31 21:00:37", "2022-05-31 23:00:10", "2022-06-01 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-01 03:00:38", "2022-06-01 05:00:36", "2022-06-01 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-01 09:00:36", "2022-06-01 11:00:36", "2022-06-01 13:00:39", 
"2022-06-01 15:00:13", "2022-06-01 17:00:37", "2022-06-01 19:00:38", 
"2022-06-01 21:00:11", "2022-06-01 23:00:37", "2022-06-02 01:00:38", 
"2022-06-02 03:00:36", "2022-06-02 05:00:38", "2022-06-02 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-02 09:00:36", "2022-06-02 11:00:10", "2022-06-02 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-02 15:00:14", "2022-06-02 17:00:37", "2022-06-02 19:00:35", 
"2022-06-02 21:00:38", "2022-06-02 23:00:36", "2022-06-03 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-03 03:00:36", "2022-06-03 05:00:15", "2022-06-03 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-03 09:00:36", "2022-06-03 11:00:24", "2022-06-03 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-03 15:00:09", "2022-06-03 17:00:37", "2022-06-03 19:00:36", 
"2022-06-03 21:00:36", "2022-06-03 23:00:12", "2022-06-04 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-04 03:00:36", "2022-06-04 05:00:09", "2022-06-04 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-04 09:00:14", "2022-06-04 11:00:37", "2022-06-04 13:00:09", 
"2022-06-04 15:00:37", "2022-06-04 17:00:09", "2022-06-04 19:00:37", 
"2022-06-04 21:00:11", "2022-06-04 23:00:37", "2022-06-05 01:00:38", 
"2022-06-05 03:00:36", "2022-06-05 05:00:38", "2022-06-05 07:00:36", 
"2022-06-05 09:00:36", "2022-06-05 11:00:36", "2022-06-05 13:00:10", 
"2022-06-05 15:00:46", "2022-06-05 17:00:38", "2022-06-05 19:00:36", 
"2022-06-05 21:00:36", "2022-06-05 23:00:10", "2022-06-06 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-06 03:00:38", "2022-06-06 05:00:34", "2022-06-06 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-06 09:00:38", "2022-06-06 11:00:38", "2022-06-06 13:00:13", 
"2022-06-06 15:00:37", "2022-06-06 17:00:19", "2022-06-06 19:00:42", 
"2022-06-06 21:00:22", "2022-06-06 23:00:37", "2022-06-07 01:00:36", 
"2022-06-07 03:00:36", "2022-06-07 05:00:12", "2022-06-07 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-07 09:00:36", "2022-06-07 11:00:33", "2022-06-07 13:00:38", 
"2022-06-07 15:00:36", "2022-06-07 17:00:37", "2022-06-07 19:00:36", 
"2022-06-07 21:00:38", "2022-06-07 23:00:36", "2022-06-08 01:00:38", 
"2022-06-08 03:00:36", "2022-06-08 05:00:38", "2022-06-08 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-08 09:00:38", "2022-06-08 11:00:38", "2022-06-08 13:00:12", 
"2022-06-08 15:00:37", "2022-06-08 17:00:37", "2022-06-08 19:00:31", 
"2022-06-08 21:00:37", "2022-06-08 23:00:36", "2022-06-09 01:00:38", 
"2022-06-09 03:00:38", "2022-06-09 05:00:36", "2022-06-09 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-09 09:00:13", "2022-06-09 11:00:37", "2022-06-09 13:00:12", 
"2022-06-09 15:00:37", "2022-06-09 17:00:37", "2022-06-09 19:00:36", 
"2022-06-09 21:00:38", "2022-06-09 23:00:36", "2022-06-10 01:00:29", 
"2022-06-10 03:00:36", "2022-06-10 05:00:20", "2022-06-10 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-10 09:00:30", "2022-06-10 11:00:38", "2022-06-10 13:00:38", 
"2022-06-10 15:00:37", "2022-06-10 17:00:11", "2022-06-10 19:00:37", 
"2022-06-10 21:00:38", "2022-06-10 23:00:38", "2022-06-11 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-11 03:00:37", "2022-06-11 05:00:42", "2022-06-11 07:00:18", 
"2022-06-11 09:00:37", "2022-06-11 11:00:38", "2022-06-11 13:00:13", 
"2022-06-11 15:00:37", "2022-06-11 17:00:34", "2022-06-11 19:00:38", 
"2022-06-11 21:00:21", "2022-06-11 23:00:37", "2022-06-12 01:00:36", 
"2022-06-12 03:00:36", "2022-06-12 05:00:44", "2022-06-12 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-12 09:00:38", "2022-06-12 11:00:38", "2022-06-12 13:00:38", 
"2022-06-12 15:00:38", "2022-06-12 17:00:36", "2022-06-12 19:00:38", 
"2022-06-12 21:00:36", "2022-06-12 23:00:38", "2022-06-13 01:00:14", 
"2022-06-13 03:00:37", "2022-06-13 05:00:38", "2022-06-13 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-13 09:00:38", "2022-06-13 11:00:33", "2022-06-13 13:00:11", 
"2022-06-13 15:00:37", "2022-06-13 17:00:36", "2022-06-13 19:00:38", 
"2022-06-13 21:00:36", "2022-06-13 23:00:15", "2022-06-14 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-14 03:00:36", "2022-06-14 05:00:38", "2022-06-14 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-14 09:00:36", "2022-06-14 11:00:15", "2022-06-14 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-14 15:00:36", "2022-06-14 17:00:40", "2022-06-14 19:00:14", 
"2022-06-14 21:00:37", "2022-06-14 23:00:36", "2022-06-15 01:00:36", 
"2022-06-15 03:00:36", "2022-06-15 05:00:36", "2022-06-15 07:00:36", 
"2022-06-15 09:00:38", "2022-06-15 11:00:11", "2022-06-15 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-15 15:00:36", "2022-06-15 17:00:12", "2022-06-15 19:00:37", 
"2022-06-15 21:00:36", "2022-06-15 23:00:38", "2022-06-16 01:00:10", 
"2022-06-16 03:00:37", "2022-06-16 05:00:36", "2022-06-16 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-16 09:00:38", "2022-06-16 11:00:21", "2022-06-16 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-16 15:00:37", "2022-06-16 17:00:38", "2022-06-16 19:00:38", 
"2022-06-16 21:00:21", "2022-06-16 23:00:37", "2022-06-17 01:00:36", 
"2022-06-17 03:00:36", "2022-06-17 05:00:36", "2022-06-17 07:00:11", 
"2022-06-17 09:00:37", "2022-06-17 11:00:12", "2022-06-17 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-17 15:00:10", "2022-06-17 17:00:36", "2022-06-17 19:01:57", 
"2022-06-17 21:00:37", "2022-06-17 23:00:22", "2022-06-18 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-18 03:00:38", "2022-06-18 05:00:38", "2022-06-18 07:00:10", 
"2022-06-18 09:00:37", "2022-06-18 11:00:11", "2022-06-18 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-18 15:00:38", "2022-06-18 17:00:11", "2022-06-18 19:00:37", 
"2022-06-18 21:00:11", "2022-06-18 23:00:37", "2022-06-19 01:00:15", 
"2022-06-19 03:00:37", "2022-06-19 05:00:38", "2022-06-19 07:00:10", 
"2022-06-19 09:00:37", "2022-06-19 11:00:10", "2022-06-19 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-19 15:00:38", "2022-06-19 17:00:36", "2022-06-19 19:00:14", 
"2022-06-19 21:00:37", "2022-06-19 23:00:15", "2022-06-20 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-20 03:00:36", "2022-06-20 05:00:20", "2022-06-20 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-20 09:00:38", "2022-06-20 11:00:36", "2022-06-20 13:00:12", 
"2022-06-20 15:00:42", "2022-06-20 17:00:38", "2022-06-20 19:00:36", 
"2022-06-20 21:00:36", "2022-06-20 23:00:11", "2022-06-21 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-21 03:00:38", "2022-06-21 05:00:36", "2022-06-21 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-21 09:00:37", "2022-06-21 11:00:13", "2022-06-21 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-21 15:00:38", "2022-06-21 17:00:34", "2022-06-21 19:00:35", 
"2022-06-21 21:00:38", "2022-06-21 23:00:33", "2022-06-22 01:00:36", 
"2022-06-22 03:00:36", "2022-06-22 05:00:38", "2022-06-22 07:00:36", 
"2022-06-22 09:00:37", "2022-06-22 11:00:36", "2022-06-22 13:00:38", 
"2022-06-22 15:00:38", "2022-06-22 17:00:36", "2022-06-22 19:00:36", 
"2022-06-22 21:00:33", "2022-06-22 23:00:10", "2022-06-23 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-23 03:00:11", "2022-06-23 05:00:37", "2022-06-23 07:00:11", 
"2022-06-23 09:00:37", "2022-06-23 11:00:36", "2022-06-23 13:00:36", 
"2022-06-23 15:00:38", "2022-06-23 17:00:21", "2022-06-23 19:00:37", 
"2022-06-23 21:00:38", "2022-06-23 23:00:36", "2022-06-24 01:00:36", 
"2022-06-24 03:00:36", "2022-06-24 05:00:40", "2022-06-24 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-24 09:00:38", "2022-06-24 11:00:44", "2022-06-24 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-24 15:00:38", "2022-06-24 17:00:37", "2022-06-24 19:00:38", 
"2022-06-24 21:00:38", "2022-06-24 23:00:38", "2022-06-25 01:00:37", 
"2022-06-25 03:00:37", "2022-06-25 05:00:11", "2022-06-25 07:00:37", 
"2022-06-25 09:00:38", "2022-06-25 11:00:38", "2022-06-25 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-25 15:00:36", "2022-06-25 17:00:36", "2022-06-25 19:00:38", 
"2022-06-25 21:00:36", "2022-06-25 23:00:38", "2022-06-26 01:00:13", 
"2022-06-26 03:00:37", "2022-06-26 05:00:36", "2022-06-26 07:00:15", 
"2022-06-26 09:00:37", "2022-06-26 11:00:36", "2022-06-26 13:00:36", 
"2022-06-26 15:00:37", "2022-06-26 17:00:36", "2022-06-26 19:00:13", 
"2022-06-26 21:00:37", "2022-06-26 23:00:36", "2022-06-27 01:00:18", 
"2022-06-27 03:00:37", "2022-06-27 05:00:38", "2022-06-27 07:00:38", 
"2022-06-27 09:00:36", "2022-06-27 11:00:39", "2022-06-27 13:00:38", 
"2022-06-27 15:00:38", "2022-06-27 17:00:36", "2022-06-27 19:00:16", 
"2022-06-27 21:00:42", "2022-06-27 23:00:36", "2022-06-28 01:00:15", 
"2022-06-28 03:00:37", "2022-06-28 05:00:38", "2022-06-28 07:00:10", 
"2022-06-28 09:00:37", "2022-06-28 11:00:38", "2022-06-28 13:00:12", 
"2022-06-28 15:00:37", "2022-06-28 17:00:38", "2022-06-28 19:00:36", 
"2022-06-28 21:00:36", "2022-06-28 23:00:38", "2022-06-29 01:00:12", 
"2022-06-29 03:00:37", "2022-06-29 05:00:36", "2022-06-29 07:00:36", 
"2022-06-29 09:00:38", "2022-06-29 11:00:11", "2022-06-29 13:00:37", 
"2022-06-29 15:00:38", "2022-06-29 17:00:36", "2022-06-29 19:00:14", 
"2022-06-29 21:00:37", "2022-06-29 23:00:38", "2022-06-30 01:00:32", 
"2022-06-30 03:00:36", "2022-06-30 05:00:37", "2022-06-30 07:00:19", 
"2022-06-30 09:00:37", "2022-06-30 11:00:38", "2022-06-30 13:00:18", 
"2022-06-30 15:00:37")), 
y = as.numeric(c("0", "250", "296", "296", "296", "18", "349", "9509", "6660", 
"28665", "26741", "9586", "7693", "6714", "6953", "7085", "6953", 
"7209", "8109", "7925", "39605", "8905", "46625", "91505", "122714", 
"118820", "116352", "116605", "102425", "101258", "97360", "120105", 
"124681", "191458", "347552", "402865", "347905", "344528", "340525", 
"340925", "346832", "359482", "379474", "319658", "334165", "382325", 
"372196", "878018", "622400", "626777", "625925", "625316", "626777", 
"600889", "634525", "608873", "626825", "815776", "832189", "851650", 
"1649645", "1618084", "1619045", "1616265", "1618618", "1618201", 
"1614290", "1640354", "1889005", "1671218", "1703362", "1575824", 
"1577242", "1578664", "1578664", "1576836", "1576450", "1623690", 
"1630628", "1822928", "1520909", "1369316", "698765", "595984", 
"175941", "177530", "176329", "176329", "171485", "176425", "113396", 
"114965", "375885", "539785", "1263629", "4560730", "5848736", 
"5814954", "5792840", "5779265", "5762997", "5785061", "5770586", 
"5385781", "4218113", "3497125", "3022696", "3432580", "3237749", 
"3004580", "2994804", "2989922", "3004580", "2961697", "3052241", 
"3085252", "3116788", "3189233", "3421217", "3517202", "3165073", 
"3166037", "3192269", "3158698", "3164625", "3157625", "3233732", 
"2571656", "1765384", "1199524", "1326496", "752050", "753761", 
"759490", "752050", "776528", "780004", "768850", "756452", "750625", 
"671432", "604981", "188546", "99905", "106434", "108352", "108404", 
"108373", "107497", "112016", "36466", "31316", "31376", "871105", 
"962065", "893012", "878837", "873157", "874961", "874660", "855880", 
"810125", "876713", "919304", "790281", "892585", "621725", "119925", 
"347418", "349960", "344962", "347321", "338405", "348885", "397489", 
"448489", "344656", "801386", "805285", "1073185", "2430650", 
"2515237", "2511169", "2513353", "2505221", "2504848", "2508025", 
"3112973", "3039769", "3287077", "3559753", "3709576", "3671386", 
"3443941", "3439624", "3460277", "3443941", "3551641", "3598946", 
"3741413", "4001488", "5378762", "6624020", "6180961", "5895284", 
"4454785", "4446965", "4443797", "4435405", "4443058", "4296436", 
"4376245", "4430504", "4037384", "4018477", "3822010", "3545401", 
"3566425", "3522025", "3511781", "3517585", "2760346", "2259469", 
"1847336", "1897706", "2950813", "4065482", "3906233", "3597625", 
"3596389", "3590197", "3583277", "3724074", "4092020", "3271140", 
"3204765", "3138890", "3166937", "3116041", "3139816", "3054356", 
"3094537", "3101653", "3101653", "3338740", "3634280", "4014400", 
"4152404", "3904130", "4140034", "3958445", "3609605", "4041850", 
"3641465", "3632980", "3625957", "3638125", "3756689", "3733218", 
"3768404", "2656834", "2689856", "3065140", "3139250", "3501241", 
"3122632", "3132685", "3305633", "3296720", "3347882", "3456626", 
"3511796", "3870800", "4365450", "4106429", "3804170", "3199618", 
"3046105", "3021005", "2941205", "2941786", "2527850", "2532008", 
"2226874", "1458437", "1139200", "1736225", "1955017", "1463641", 
"2681485", "2668388", "2972164", "2939770", "2898794", "3037005", 
"3032657", "3037042", "2224845", "1843594", "427825", "2032804", 
"1796237", "1797650", "1739890", "1743625", "1646618", "1659065", 
"1240640", "2002973", "2045905", "2002005", "2275025", "2975378", 
"2880098", "2877064", "2883348", "3136562", "2942010", "2926820", 
"1897785", "1611553", "1348650", "2082500", "3976498", "3594530", 
"3293537", "3300485", "3411733", "3538261", "3584650", "3846586", 
"4320145", "3159961", "3899033", "4536853", "7919045", "8138338", 
"8170562", "8171144", "8187280", "8739989", "8624213", "10672208", 
"12380329", "14025076", "14135081", "11942125", "10223641", "7110868", 
"6239162", "6413765", "6370865", "6755689", "7185130", "7205129", 
"10424765", "14121549", "14887784", "13125193", "13345153", "12400400", 
"11877220", "11875978", "11846992", "11961181", "12558349", "12447441", 
"11277045", "10537748", "8626693", "5185000", "2698393", "1032541", 
"1617480", "1577300", "1574897", "1305032", "1148669", "1304488", 
"1957625", "9706010", "21182522", "31547693", "67021378", "93230050", 
"108139565", "115020929", "115470592", "115528849", "109662692", 
"113301770", "115077800", "109617265", "108071818", "113694848", 
"124578802", "130818818", "126816050", "126866170", "126422948", 
"131251364", "117576505", "117487460", "118662701", "109143242", 
"100710965", "100992578", "103028756", "96220573", "95056361", 
"95151137", "95092308", "95876168", "93260872", "94637266", "96123400", 
"106539605", "104521853", "105794900", "105800818", "104635880", 
"103933370", "103885301", "103847201", "105853985", "110371428", 
"110191250", "110144905", "109597085", "109028369", "101699865", 
"98249530", "97586345", "94895720", "94867721", "94921346", "98452274", 
"99055090", "99187002", "99514133", "103372154", "97692149", 
"101592313", "94516825", "93206105", "93894692", "93877621", 
"93868450", "93758242", "95593000", "93503588", "89236485", "91984129", 
"92406632")))

# Fit the piecewise regression model
model <- lm(y ~ x, data = data)
segmented_model <- segmented(model, seg.Z = ~ x)

I've tried to use x in the lm() in both POSIXct format and as.numeric() and correspondingle in the "seg.Z =" argument for segmented() but in either case the resulting error is "Error in obj0$residuals : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors."
I do not get the same error when using a basic example like the one in this article: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2023/12/unraveling-patterns-a-step-by-step-guide-to-piecewise-regression-in-r/
Thanks for your help.
